# Force datatables column to take up full width on small screen

Tags: javascript, css, datatables

**BACKGROUND:** I have a jQuery datatable on my website that I want to look, act, and feel like a table on desktop sizes. When it hits a small screen size (as definied by Foundation - 39.9375em), I want to hide the header and footer (which I already basically figured out) and have the first column take up the full width of the page and force all the other columns to a child row. The other columns just have buttons/links that take you to other pages having to do with the name of the row. Things like settings, status, etc.

**QUESTION:** How do I force the column to take up the full width?

**WHAT I'VE ALREADY TRIED:** I tried setting `white-space: nowrap`, but then it just responsive hides the whole column and then I'm left with literally just the control thing. So it's like an accordion. I tried to look up how to force the other columns to be hidden responsively, but I couldn't find anything and I can't think of any way to do it myself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you create the table with the `<table>` tag or the  `display:table;` css property?

Comment: The `<table>` tag

Comment: Then use the `colspan` attribute on the td you want to be full width. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Comment: Please elaborate. I don't get how that would help me. Maybe in an answer instead of the comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some playing around, I found a solution on this page of the datatables documentation: https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/classes. For all of the columns except the title column, I simply put `className: 'min-tablet-l'`. That way, as soon as we hit landscape tablet size, the columns are automatically thrown into the child row and the control turns up that lets me show/hide it is shown too.